# AVSpeechSynthesizer delegate breaks speech

Tags: ios, accessibility, text-to-speech

Setting `AVSpeechSynthesizer.delegate = self` breaks french hyphenated words.

e.g. “parlez-vous” will be pronounced “parlez”,

"attendez-vous" will be pronounced  "attendez",

"est-ce qu'il est la?" will be pronounced  "est    qu'il est la?"

"Puis-je vous voir demain?" will be pronounced "Puis vous voir demain?"

If you listen you can tell that the second word is silent ... like there seems to be the correct space left for it.

I have sent feedback FB11968008 to Apple.

No problem in the simulator - this is a device only problem occuring on these devices.

iPhone 11 iOS 16.2

iPhone 8  iOS 16.1.2

iPad Air2 iOS 15.7.2

Xcode 14.2

Any thoughts?

CODE DEMONSTRATION:

```
import SwiftUI
import Speech

struct ContentView: View {
    var synth = SpeechSynthesizer()
    @State var isDelegateSet = true
    var sentences: [String] = [
        "Parlez-vous ",
        "attendez-vous ",
        "est-ce qu'il est la?",
        "Puis-je vous voir demain?"
    ]
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            List {
                ForEach(sentences.indices, id: \.self) { index in
                    Button(sentences[index]) {
                        synth.toggleAVSpeechSynthesizerDelegate(isDelegateSet: isDelegateSet)
                        synth.speak(string: sentences[index])
                    }
                }
                Toggle("toggle AVSpeechSynthesizer delegate", isOn: $isDelegateSet)
                Text(isDelegateSet ? "AVSpeechSynthesizer.delegate = self \nSpeech is INCORRECT " : "AVSpeechSynthesizer.delegate = nil \nSpeech is correct")
                    .padding()
            }
        }
    }
}


class SpeechSynthesizer: NSObject, ObservableObject, AVSpeechSynthesizerDelegate {
    var synthesizer = AVSpeechSynthesizer()
    var utterance = AVSpeechUtterance(string: "")
    
    override init() {
        super.init()
        synthesizer.delegate = self
    }
    
    func speak(string: String) {
        synthesizer.stopSpeaking(at: .immediate)
        utterance = AVSpeechUtterance(string: string)
        utterance.voice = AVSpeechSynthesisVoice(language: "fr-FR")
        synthesizer.speak(utterance)
    }
    
    func toggleAVSpeechSynthesizerDelegate(isDelegateSet: Bool) {
        if isDelegateSet {
            synthesizer.delegate = self
        }
        else {
            synthesizer.delegate = nil
        }
    }
    
    
    func speechSynthesizer(_ synthesizer: AVSpeechSynthesizer, willSpeakRangeOfSpeechString characterRange: NSRange, utterance: AVSpeechUtterance) {
        // if synthesizer.delegate = self , phrases are spoken incorrectly. !!
        // if synthesizer.delegate = nil  , phrases are spoken correctly as delegates are not called. !!
    }
}
```

Comment: Workaround: replace "-" by " " in your string before reading out for french words? 

Comment: @XLE_22 thanks, I do have that fix in my app already but the app is more complex and this messes things up. Also "Où va-t-il?" being pronounced "Où va t il?" is wrong.